# How to find the x-intercept of a plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, intercept

I know there must be a really simple answer to this question, but I just can't seem to find it. (Guess I'm probably Googling the wrong terms.)

I am plotting some data in Matlab using the *plot(x, data)* function.

I want to find the x-intercept(s) of the line, i.e. the point(s) where y = 0.

In some cases, it may be that the *data* vector doesn't actually contain values equal to zero, so it's not just a matter of finding the indexes of the elements in *data* which are equal to zero, and then finding the corresponding elements in the *x* vector.

Like I said, it's a really simple problem and I'd think there's already some in-built function in Matlab...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In case there is no point with `y` exactly equal to 0, do you want a closest point to y==0 or you want to interpolate between closest points or may be through the whole line series?

Comment: @yuk The data I have always intersects the x-intercept. So even though the vector itself does not have 0 as one of its values, I'd like to get the point where the line (plotted by Matlab) intersects the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find X-intercept as interpolate between 2 closest points around X axes you can use INTERP1 function:

```
x0 = interp1(y,x,0);
```

It will work if `x` and `y` are monotonically increasing/decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=-1.999:0.001:1.999;
y=(x-1).*(x+1); 
plot(x,y) 
hold on
plot(x,zeros(length(x),1),'--r') 
find(abs(y)<1e-3)
```

So the last part will guarantee that even there is not exact y-intercept, you will still get a close value. The result of this code are the indices that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a linear fit (1st order polynomial) to your data, then, from the slope and Y intercept of the fitted line, you'll be able to find X intercept. Here is an example:

```
x1 = 1:10;
y1 = x1 + randn(1,10);
P = polyfit(x1,y1,1);
xint = -P(2)/P(1);
```

if you want to know what is the slope and y_int, here it is:

```
Slope = P(1);  % if needed 
yint = P(2);   % if need
```