# Extract x and y intercept from plot

Tags: matlab, plot, intersection

I have plotted some data in MATLAB (see figure below). 
How can I extract the x and y intercepts from the plot without manually estimating them?

[image: plot with two lines]

Comment: How did you plot the data? Your plot inputs should be your x and y interceptions.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The data I have plotted are not continous points. Its a finite number of points which do not necesserily include points on the interceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x0 = interp1(y,x,0,'spline');
y0 = interp1(x,y,0,'spline');
```

Similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982833/how-to-find-the-x-intercept-of-a-plot-in-matlab), except you'll need to play with the method and maybe even the extrapolation as described on [this Matlab page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#btwp6lt-1-method).

Comment: Post showing impacts of different interpolation [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524024/8239061)